# Excel - Combining two formulas into one

Tags: excel

How do I combine these two formulas and turn 0 into a `BLANK` response:

```
=INDEX($A:$A,SMALL(IF($B:$B<=$G$3,ROW($B:$B)),ROW(2:2)))
=INDEX($A:$A,SMALL(IF($C:$C<=$H$3,ROW($B:$B)),ROW(2:2)))
```

I have two columns that I am trying to reference to spit out multiple values for the possible outcome of two separate input values. For Example:

```
A         B                   C
SCAC      Linear Feet         Weight
PITD      20                  10000
ESTE      10                  15000
SAIA      25                  20000
ABFS      20                  25000
```

Input Values

```
Linear Feet     Weight
20              20000
```

If the entered field is greater than or equal to I want it to return all values that match the criteria

Sorry guys, I just word from my boss who wants the INPUT values to be either/or a match for LINEAR FEET or WEIGHT...any ideas to accommodate this new ask?

Return

```
SCAC Code
PITD    
SAIA
ABFS
```

Answer (score 1):

You add the second criteria only:

```
=INDEX($A:$A,SMALL(IF(($B:$B<=$G$3)*($C:$C<=$H$3),ROW($B:$B)),ROW(2:2)))
```

This is an array formula and needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

The `*` is similar to `AND` for `OR` use `+` instead.

---

***Warning***

Array formulas should not use full column references but only reference the data set:

```
=INDEX($A:$A,SMALL(IF(($B1:$B100<=$G$3)*($C1:$C100<=$H$3),ROW($B1:$B100)),ROW(2:2)))
```

Array formulas will iterate the entire range asked so the original will do over 2 million calculations.

---

If you want the best of both worlds, dynamic dataset (so you do not need to change the formula when new data is added) and only iterate over the cells with data, we can use INDEX/MATCH to locate and set the last cell with data.

We would use MATCH to find the last row in Column A with a value: `MATCH("ZZZ",A:A)` and then use INDEX of each column to limit the arrays:

```
=INDEX($A:$A,SMALL(IF(($B$1:INDEX($B:$B,MATCH("ZZZ",$A:$A))<=$G$3)*($C$1:INDEX($C:$C,MATCH("ZZZ",$A:$A))<=$H$3),ROW($B$1:INDEX($B:$B,MATCH("ZZZ",$A:$A)))),ROW(2:2)))
```

This then will increase the data set as data is added and shrink the data set as data is removed.

Comment: Sorry guys, I just word from my boss who wants the INPUT values to be either/or a match for LINEAR FEET or WEIGHT...any ideas to accommodate this new ask?

Comment: Just use `+` in place of `*`